# Creating a php search from Mysql database

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I am building a bus reservation system using php & mysql.
In here I am trying to input the search field "route" which is fields of the mysql table. 
It seems to have problem in searching and printing the results to the page. Please help me out.

```
<?php 
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tsms");
$output ='';
if(isset($_POST['from'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['from'];
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bus WHERE route='$serchq' ");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count==0){
        echo "<script>
alert('No bus services are found');
</script>"; 
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $imageData = $row['image'];
            $arrival = $row['arrival_time'];
            $departure = $row['departure_time'];
            $type = $row['bus_type'];
            $class = $row['class'];
            $name = $row['bus_name'];
            $facilities = $row['facilities'];
            $reservation = $row['reservation_fee'];
            $output = '<div>'.$arrival.''.$departure.''.$type.''.$class.''.$name.''.$facilities.''.$reservation.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: _It seems to have problem in searching and printing_ Can you be more specific? BTW your questions have got a high potential for sql injections.

Comment: are you talking about dropdown searching..

Comment: it doesn't show any result. No errors also.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is the problem, but the sql comparison with "=" searches for a perfect match. Try to use the "like" as 
SELECT * FROM bus WHERE route like '%$serchq%'
also, do escape the serchq, because you can get hacked this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your search form, do you have a  (dropdown) input or a simple text input? 
In your sql query, you are searching for an exact match. 
Should this be your issue, consider changing "route='$serchq'" to "route LIKE $serchq" for a more broad match. Also the quotes are not necessary around $serch so eliminating them might help.

Comment: it is a dropdown which is fetching the route from the same table. user gets the chance to select the route and according to his selection the busses should be displyed